# How to have visitors mine on my websites and is it legal?

Tags: mining, miners

I was wondering how to have visitors on my website mine monero for me and if it is legal or not. I know that if I don't tell them its illegal, but I plan on telling them in the footer of my website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but I can't imagine a reason why it should be illegal even if you're not explicitly asking for their permissions. They're visiting __your__ website after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you ask for their permission I can't see why it could be considered illegal. Coinhive considers it a viable alternative to adverts thus not illegal. In addition I don't think mining on peoples computers using a webpage is any worse than reselling customer information to advertisers.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to Coinhive? Other web miner scripts that I can insert to my html page?

Comment: @AncientBehemoth Sorry not aware of any